# Why is there no output when I change the characters in a string?

Tags: c++, c++14

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    s[0] = 'b';
    s[1] = 'a';
    s[2] = '\0';
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

I declare a string in my code and than assign character values using array indices. When I print the string it gives me no output. My question is why not?

What is the reason that it is giving no output?

Comment: Replace `cout << s;` with `cout << s.length();` and you will understand, why it happens. Don't spam tags! There's nothing to C here.

Comment: Please review your grammar in both the title and your description. [learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h?noredirect=1

Comment: When trying @S.M. 's advice, comment out character assignment as well, otherwise you still might not see any output (due to programme crash...).

Comment: **Recommended reading:** [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648)

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do has [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

`string s;` default initializes (size is zero), then you access elements that are not there.

To solve it you can simply use `string s = "ab";` or

```
std::string s;
s.push_back('b');
s.push_back('a');
```

or as @bindsniper001 suggested(you cannot add to the length of the string this way though):

```
std::string s2(2, ' ');
s2[0] = 'c';
s2[1] = 'd';
```

Live on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/XRi-UI)

Comment: To add to this, you can modify the characters in a string using array syntax, but you can't add to its length that way. This would also be true if you were working with a raw array. You need to know how long the array is before you try to access its elements.